# Making up-sells have price magento 1.5

Tags: magento-1.5, up-sells

I’m kind of new with magento and I'm making an up-sell for some of my products, and they are showing at the end of the page, but they are without the price, and I want to know how can I make magento to show the prices of the up-sells products that are linked, also if there’s a possibility to show the description of the products too that will be great.

Thanks in advantage

Comment: 1. I understand nothing, maybe add a few screenshots to explain, 2. UPDATE. Magento 1.5 is a big security problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for up-sell product description you can get product id from `$_link` object

and you want product description so you can get from

```
$test=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_link->getId())
```

and you can get description from `$test`

```
$test->getDescription()
```

and you can get price from `$_link` object

it may help you

Comment: Word of caution: I would advise against reloading the product model in this scope as it loads the entire product model... May negatively impact performance.

Comment: Besides you shouldn't load a model in a view template file anyhow.... It's against best practice. Cheers.

Comment: without reloading product object how we can achieve that?

Comment: because in $_link object you can get short description not description

Comment: Well there are a few ways. Link is from a collection and assigned in a loop. Rewrite the collection that link comes from and use addAttributeToSelect('description'). Another way would be to call getResource()->getBackend()and load the description into the currently loaded model.

Answer (score 0):

look into the file `yourtemplate/catalog/product/list/upsell.phtml` you will find code for displaying price.

The code to display price of upsell product is

`<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_link, true, '-upsell') ?`

Insert the code in upsell.phtml and you will see the price of your upsells product